# ethernet sharing stopped working

Tags: connection, sharing

I have upgraded from 21.10 to 22.04 LTS and wired ethernet shared to other computers has stopped working. Link continually goes up and down.
dmesg output:

```
[  522.627611] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-0-2e00:00: Downshift occurred from negotiated speed 1Gbps to actual speed 100Mbps, check cabling!
[  522.627633] r8169 0000:2e:00.0 enp46s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full (downshifted) - flow control off
[  522.630684] r8169 0000:2e:00.0 enp46s0: Link is Down
[  536.461264] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-0-2e00:00: Downshift occurred from negotiated speed 1Gbps to actual speed 100Mbps, check cabling!
[  536.461285] r8169 0000:2e:00.0 enp46s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full (downshifted) - flow control off
[  536.464575] r8169 0000:2e:00.0 enp46s0: Link is Down
[  551.156791] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-0-2e00:00: Downshift occurred from negotiated speed 1Gbps to actual speed 100Mbps, check cabling!
[  551.156812] r8169 0000:2e:00.0 enp46s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full (downshifted) - flow control off
[  551.159671] r8169 0000:2e:00.0 enp46s0: Link is Down
```

anyone have any clue how to solve this?